# Zabbix discovered nodes count change trigger

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I made a zabbix template and scripts for my OpenVPN server. This template generates VPN users (as discovered nodes) from certificate list. Every node is monitored for traffic, up/down, uptime. All users are placed in VPNUsers group.

I'm trying to make trigger to raise alert when new users added or removed. I studied documentation and found groupsum function, but can't figure out how use it to compare current sum and previous.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discovery part was not clear to me, but grpsum is an [aggregate item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate) function. The values would be stored in an item, and then on top of that you'd create a trigger with, for example, `abschange()<>0` [trigger function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).

Comment: So I added aggregated grpsum item into parent vpn server node and then added a trigger with abschange() in it. Works!. Thanks!